# What is content%args.__dict__?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm confused with a statement, found [in post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50856325/run-command-line-containing-multiple-strings-from-python-script?noredirect=1#comment88741916_50856325):

```
with open('cover.tex','w') as f:
    f.write(content%args.__dict__)
```

What exactly is `content%args.__dict__`? Is this Python 2.7? Quick googling/asking did not help.

Update: one suggestion is that `%` is [modulo division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432208/how-does-work-in-python), by how is it applicable to a string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does % work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432208/how-does-work-in-python) See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14886799/2072269

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`content` contains strings of the form `"%(key)s"` The `%` operator here is the string interpolation operator, and it will cause the value of `args.__dict__["key"]` to be substituted for `"%(key)s"` in the string that is written out.